# Predicate Logic Proof Help! ∃xAx ∨ ∃yFy , ∀x(Ax → Fx) |= ∃xFx

Tags: logic, proof, predicate-logic

I am unable to prove it :(
I think I need to assume - ∃xFx but what follows later on?

Comment: Apply Disjunction Elimination to 1st premise.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Proof By Cases.

Assuming *each* case of the first premise `∃xAx ∨ ∃yFy`, in turn derive the conclusion `∃xFx` in two subproof.

Assuming the left case holds, there will be a witness `c` where `Ac` and by universal instantiation of the second premise, `Ac → Fc` will also hold, from which you can derive `Fc` for the witness.  Thus deriving `∃xFx` in the first case.

Assuming the right case holds, it is trivial to derive `∃xFx`.

Since `∃xFx` may be derived from both cases of the disjunction under the premises, we may infer that `∃xFx` is entailed by the premises.